# Can't display Image in PDF-File if height > 72px

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I created a PDF-File with XSL. What iam trying to do is displaying a image with

```
<fo:block >                       
 <fo:external-graphic src="url('{.//ImagePfad}')"  />                      
</fo:block>
```

Its working fine with that as long as the picture has a height of 72px. If i change for example the height to 73, the image is no longer displayed. What could be the problem? How can i display images with a higher height?

Can someone help please help me with that

Answer (score 1):

I found the solutions on my self. I had to to set the region-before higher